# Send button with certain features

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

## Javascript

```
$(function(){
  $('.select-another-button').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
      $(this).attr('disabled','true'); //disables the button
      $('#overlay').show(); //after disabling show the overlay for hover
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(this).attr('disabled','false'); //enables after 5mins
        $('#overlay').hide(); //hide the overlay
      }, 300000);
      e.preventDefault();
      fileBrowser(this);
      return false;
    });
  });
});

$("#overlay").hover(function(){
    $('#message').show();
},function(){
    $('#message').hide();
});
```

## CSS

```
.title-actions {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 13px; }
  .title-actions a {
    transition: background 0.3s ease; }
    .title-actions a.btn {
      padding: 2px 14px;
      line-height: 26px;
      max-height: 28px;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
      margin-left: 8px; }
    .title-actions a:hover {
      background: #4382b5; }
  .title-actions span {
    color: #444;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 6px; }
  .title-actions .btn {
    padding: 2px 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    max-height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    margin-left: 8px; }
  .title-actions .btn-icon {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;il 
    color: #3e5366;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 !important;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: 6px; }
    .title-actions .btn-icon i {
      font-size: 35px;
      line-height: 20px;
      position: relative;
      top: 12px; }
    .title-actions .btn-icon:hover {
      color: #4382b5;
      background: transparent; }
  .title-actions .badge .material-icons {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px; }
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

## HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <a href="#"
           title="{% trans "Send email - rejected file(s)" %}"
           class="btn btn-icon select-another-button"
           data-url="{% url "messaging:send" request_id=object.pk %}">
            <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
            <div class='alert alert-success' id='send-message' style="display: none;">
                <p>
                The message was sent to the client. Please wait 5 minutes <br> before sending the message again.
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

## Django

I have this in my urls.py file

```
app_name = 'messaging'
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    url(r'^send/(?P<request_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        send, name='send'),
]
```

The django's method is Send button with certain features

```
@staff_member_required
@csrf_exempt
def send(request, request_id=None):
    req= Request.objects.get(pk=request_id)
    request_folders = req.folder.all_files.all()
    context = []

    for doc in request_folders:
        if doc.meta.state == u'rejected':
            context.append(doc)

    if context:
        ctx = {'request': req}
        EmailFromTemplate('document-refusal', extra_context=ctx)\
            .send_to(req.customer.user)

    return HttpResponse('')
```

I've created a button which send an email under certain conditions. I'd like once I send a message to deactivate the button for five minutes and then display a pop-up message which will display the remaining time before they have the possibility to send the email again. The message may be '*It remains 3 minutes and 20 secondes before you may send the message again.*'. This message will be displayed if and only if the cursor is on the button and nothing will happen otherwise. So far when I clicked the button, it turned off, but nothing else happened. I mean django's function is never called, .... How could I fix it so that it'll do what I want? How could I display the remaining time in that message? With `JsonResponse()`?

**Edit :**

I have another issue with `setTimeout`. It is easy for the client to just reload the page to skip the 5 minutes wait. By what could I substitute `setTimeout` so that it will not do such thing?

Comment: First of all I think you just didn't put the right message Id there. In your javascript change your `$("#message")` to `$("#send-message")`

Comment: @Leila Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem so far?

Comment: @J.Doe, Even if you make it work this code won't stop anyone from reloading the page and sending messages earlier than your limit. I'm sorry, but this solution looks useless.

Comment: @KoshVery Yes, I know that. According to you, is there a clever way to modify it so that it work well even if we reload the page? Could I substitute setTimeout by something else?

Comment: @J.Doe, Since we cannot trust the client we have to store and check this info on the server-side. Let only logged in users can send messages. Write `user_id` + `last_msg_time` to the DB. When the client requests the page, you check if time is up for this user. If the user can send a msg show them the form. If they cannot send yet then show them remaining time instead of the form.  After the user sent a message show them remining time as well, but if they reload the page they won't see the form again untill time's up.  It's more complex approach, but more bulletproof. Hope it helps.

Comment: @J.Doe, Also check user's time in your server `send` method before sending the message. In case if someone obtained the form by mistake or sent the message directly to your server e. g. via `curl`.

Comment: @KoshVery Ok, assume everything is well for that issue. How could I fix my problem of with the django method 'send'?

Comment: @J.Doe, sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: The message I want to send to a client in using the django method `send` is never... le function is never called, but I don't know why... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the time left you can use something like this:

```
$(function(){
var timeout;
  $('.select-another-button').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
      $(this).attr('disabled','true'); //disables the button
      $('#overlay').show(); //after disabling show the overlay for hover
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(this).attr('disabled','false'); //enables after 5mins
        $('#overlay').hide(); //hide the overlay
      }, 300000);
      e.preventDefault();
      fileBrowser(this);
      return false;
    });
  });
});

$("#overlay").hover(function(){
  var timeleft =  Math.ceil((timeout._idleStart + timeout._idleTimeout - Date.now()) / 1000);
    $('#send-message').html("Please wait" + timeleft).show();
},function(){
    $('#send-message').hide();
});
```

If `show()` and `hide()` didn't work, try `.css("display","block")`